# error analyzing package when updating app from notification

Tags: android, updates, android-notifications

I want my app to download an updated apk of the same app when the user clicks the notification that my app creates.

Everything works good but when the user clicks the notification a window shows saying that there was an error analyzing the package.

The apk is in my personal web page like this ....com/xxxxxx.apk, i can download and install it manually using chrome or by usb, but not by clicking the notification.

Here is my code:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://....com/xxxxxxxxx.apk"),//written like this to keep privacy
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, promptInstall, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Actualizacion disponible")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```